# ApiGee InvalidateCache policy

Tags: apigee

I wanted to have simple session management at *ApiGee* side so I decided to keep session state in a cache. I used *PopulateCache*, *LookupCache* and *InvalidateCache* policies to implement that. The problem is when this specific policy is attached to the *flow* (no matter *pre-flow*, *post-flow* or any specific flow) then the *revision* cannot be deployed properly although *ApiGee* UI says it was successfully deployed (the green circle next to environment name on *Deployment* button). When I try to throw request at the proxy I got

```
{
    fault: {
        faultstring: "Internal server error APIProxy revision 1 of myapp does not exist in environment test of     organization marcinklopotek",
        detail: {
            errorcode: "messaging.adaptors.http.ServerError"
        }
    }
}
```

Redeploying doesn't help either.

---

I managed to isolate the case to reproduce the problem.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new proxy with *No Target Starting Point Type*.
2. Go to *Develop* view.
3. Choose *Invalidate Cache* policy form the *New Policy* list.
4. Attach the policy to the *PostFlow* and the *Response* segment.
5. Remove *<CacheResource>default</CacheResource>* line from the policy file (to use built in cache)
6. Save the revision using *Save* button.

**Expected results:**

- ability to serve requests to the proxy
- ability to start trace session

**Actual results:**

-- sending request to the proxy causes error

```
{
    fault: {
        faultstring: "Internal server error APIProxy revision 1 of No-Target does not exist in environment test of organization marcinklopotek",
        detail: {
           errorcode: "messaging.adaptors.http.ServerError"
        }
    }
}
```

-- starting trace session causes an error

```
Error creating trace session for API proxy No-Target, revision 1, environment test.
Failed to create DebugSession 1406889941313
```

**Additional Info:**

-- detaching and removing the policy doesn't help either and is causing the same errors

-- detaching and removing the policy and saving new revision causes

```
Error Deploying
Path /no-target conflicts with existing deployment path for revision 1 of the APIProxy No-Target in organization marcinklopotek
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a product issue with Apigee.  When using an InvalidateCache policy without a cache resource, there are problems deploying the proxy.  The workaround is to create a cache resource in the environment and refer to that in the policy: